# Android pop up list dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to add an dialog to my application.  I want it to launch as soon as the first activity loads. But instead of having just a single message to display and having a 'yes' and 'no' button like this[image]

I want it to display a list of message like this
[image]
If there is a tutorial that speaks on this subject I would be happy to look at it and also I would anybody by any chance know how to align these list with bulletins.

Comment: Make a layout that looks like that and use it in the dialog.

Comment: @BobbyDigital Do you know how i can get this dialog to only display only when the app has been launched for the first time after installation and then never again shall be displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1    Create a custom dialog layout (XML file).
 2   Attach the layout to Dialog.
  3  Display the Dialog.
   4 Done.
[Tutorial here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/)

Comment: Do you know how i can get this dialog to only display only when the app has been launched for the first time after installation and then never again shall be displayed

Answer (score 1):

> If there is a tutorial that speaks on this subject I would be happy to look at it

Your best bet would be to start [Here in the Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). They show a great example of doing it with a `Dialog`.

Another option, if this can be the entire `Activity` since you want it to happen when if first starts, is to use a `ListView` for your `Activity` and use `setChoiceMode()` on it. You can find more about that in [the Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3achoiceMode)

With this second option, you can make the `Activity` appear as a `Dialog` by adding this line to your `<activity>` tag in the `manifest.xml`

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

Comment: Do you know how i can get this dialog to only display only when the app has been launched for the first time after installation and then never again shall be displayed

Comment: Yes, you can use `SharedPreferences` and set a value the first time it is run. You check that value every time the `Activity` is started and do what you need depending on that value. [The docs have a great example of how to use SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)